# How do I determine if a subset is a vector space/linear space living in the ambient space of a R3? How do I guess the dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not really sure what the first step is. I know that we have to follow the three rules.

1. Having a 0 vector in the space
2. Closed under scalar addition
3. Closed under multiplication

The problem I'm confused with {(x, y, z) ∈ R3 | y = x + 1}

Please don't just give me the answer or do the problem for me. I'm just looking for what the first step is.

I know we have to get into a matrix, but I'm just a little confused on how. The matrix represents the vector space right? I'm also  confused about what Closed under scalar addition and Closed under multiplication mean.

Comment: First check if the vector $(0,0,0)$ in that set? Be careful getting into a matrix, look what happened to Keanu Reeves.

Comment: Hey. So do I plug in zero for x and y in that equation? There is no Z?

Comment: Read what you wrote for 1. Can that vector be an element of the set?

Comment: What do you mean by There is no $z$?

Comment: Hey I think I figured it out. If we set x, y, and z to zero. Then {0, 0, 0} does not hold under scalar multiplication. Here’s why: So if everything is zero that means y= 0 and x = 0. So  0+ 1 = 1 so y =1. If we then multiply the vector by  the scaler 2. 2*{0, 0, 0} we get {0, 0, 0}. However, this does not satisfy the such that condition because x and y are the same and y is not one more than x. For this to hold, it has to be true in all circumstances. Therefore, this is not living in R3.

Comment: All you need to note is that $(0,0,0)$ cannot be an element of the set. Since $0 \neq 0+1$ you are done. No need for scalar anything. Both the point and the set are in $\mathbb{R}^3$.